# How to activate statusbar?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
pencere = Tk()
def f3():
    if f2==True:
        statusbar = 1
def f4():
...
...
statusbar = 0 #not working
statusbar = Label(pencere,text=f"Status={statusbar}") 
pencere.mainloop()
```

I tried this code and statusbar didn't change on values, I expected the result as 0 to 1 or 1 to 0, if the program is working then statusbar will be 1, otherwise will be 0. Maybe I'm wrong on connecting statusbar to f4. Could you help me with your skills and knowledge please?

Comment: `statusbar` is a local variable inside the `f3` function, so assigning to that variable will **not** affect the the global variable of the same name.  If you want it to be global, add `global statusbar` to the top of that function.

Comment: Also, where is `f3()` actually called?

Comment: @JohnGordon: just making `statusbar` global won't affect the text on the label. The label has to be explicitly configured to show a new value.

Comment: line 5, in f3
    if f2==True:
NameError: name 'f2' is not defined. Did you mean: 'f3'?